# Number generator from 1-9999

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I created a number generator to create numbers from `0001` to `9999` but ended up creating 1 without the zeros:

```
1
2
3
etc.
```

code I am using:

```py
def my_gen(start, end, step):
    while start < end:
        start += step
        yield start

for x in my_gen(1, 1000, 2):
    print x
```

Answer (score 1):

Zeros on the left side of the `int` objects are not permitted, Python gives you SyntaxError. In math there is no difference between `0001` and `1`.

Instead you can have `str`. `"0001"` is now different from `"1"`.

with `zfill` - compatible with Python 2.7:

```py
for x in range(1, 100, 2):
    print(str(x).zfill(4))
```

or
with `f-string` - Python 3.6+:

```py
for x in range(1, 100, 2):
    print(f"{x:04}")
```

With `format()` compatible with Python 2.7:

```py
for x in range(1, 100, 2):
    print(format(x, '04'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need strings, note that you could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this purpose:

```
from itertools import product

my_gen = map(''.join, (product('0123456789', repeat=4)))
```

```
list(my_gen)
# ['0000', '0001', ... '9999']
```